# How to deploy an ionic2 application on a tomcat server

Tags: angular, ionic2, web-deployment

I have developed a web application using angular2 and ionic2. I wanted to deploy this application in a tomcat server. During development I have run this using the "ionic serve" command and the application will run on localhost. Now I wanted to move this application to a tomcat web sever, Can some one give the steps to deploy the same. Thanks in Advance.

Sathyan

Answer (score 0):

first, execute `ionic platform add browser`,

second, execute `ionic build browser`,

third, open the directory of '**< your project name >/platforms/browser/www**', and copy all the files to your tomcat server.